# How can I append elements with iterating attributes?

Tags: javascript, append, iteration

I wrote a script that isn't behaving as intended. It contains an object that is supposed to produce a paragraph element, which can then be assigned the text of it's own creation iteration, appending each new element until the for loop converges. For the purposes of highlighting my approach, I have emulated the for loop iteration manually, removing unnecessary confusion.

```js
var myElement=document.createElement('p');

myElement.setAttribute('id','one');
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML='one';

myElement.setAttribute('id','two');
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML='two';
```

As you can see, the result produces a single element instead of two, which is strange because I definitely iterated the append line at least twice, and that element contains only the text specified in the second iteration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it

```
var myElement=document.createElement('p');

myElement.setAttribute('id','one');
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML='one';

myElement=document.createElement('p'); //this new line is added
myElement.setAttribute('id','two');
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML='two';
```

basically you were making changes in the same element instead of creating new element.

for making multiple paragraphs in a loop

```
function makeNewParagraph(id, text)
{
    var myElement=document.createElement('p');
    myElement.setAttribute('id',id);
    document.body.appendChild(myElement);
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML=text;
    return myElement;
}
var numArray = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
numArray.forEach( function(value){
  makeNewParagraph(value, value);
} );
```

Comment: What if I wanted to make an constructor for my paragraph that could be called to produce paragraph objects with iterating id's?

Comment: @Musixauce3000 then also you need to create a new paragraph element everytime.